# "Runner quits expectedly" error when xcode build is done on all apps after upgrading to Monterey macOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter

After upgrading to Monterey I am unable to run any ios app on my M1 macbook pro ... What is the issue here?

```
Problem Report from Runner

Incident Identifier: 0120E59B-934C-4F55-B35E-E0BEA32A0912
CrashReporter Key:   0EFFD5AD-F351-AC39-86B5-8CC273B37EFF
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro17,1
Process:             Runner [3189]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BB8DA5E7-D3C6-4F20-BF7C-B72B2092441B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B85F43AA-1DA7-4155-BBAD-2D79794A87BB/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.example.test
Version:             1.0.0 (1)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [509]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.BB8DA5E7-D3C6-4F20-BF7C-B72B2092441B [596]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [488]

Date/Time:           2021-06-18 02:58:02.5885 +0500
Launch Time:         2021-06-18 02:57:59.8846 +0500
OS Version:          macOS 12.0 (21A5248p)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4310077440
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      mapped file                 100e69000-100e6d000    [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...t_id=2467e501
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [3189]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:



Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffdfabd8 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x100e9de5c ???
2   dyld                                   0x20102f88f dyld4::prepareSim(dyld4::RuntimeState&, char const*) + 890
3   dyld                                   0x20102e6b5 dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 244
4   dyld                                   0x20102e4b4 start + 388
5   ???                                            0x3 ???

Thread 1:: com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffde7320 ???
1   ???                                 0x7ff7ffe001a0 ???


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000108ef4af8  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000001
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x0000000109591000
   r8: 0x270529b6e6b600a7   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000109591000  r11: 0x00000001093b4010
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x00000001093b4060  r14: 0x000000020109d080  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: <unavailable>       rfl: 0x0000000000000283
 tmp0: 0x0000000100e8bc64 tmp1: 0x0000000100e8af8c tmp2: 0x0000000201047ca3


Binary Images:
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???
       0x201029000 -        0x201090fff dyld (*) <4e207376-cc5d-3986-a0bd-4d09f4217e68> /usr/lib/dyld

EOF

Model: MacBookPro17,1, BootROM 7429.0.72.0.3, proc 8:4:4 processors, 8 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_AppleM1Item, Apple M1, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: LPDDR4
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi, wl0: May  4 2021 18:24:35 version 18.20.281.2.7.8.107 FWID 01-7c11bd60
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.
```

flutter doctor -v

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on macOS 12.0 21A5248p darwin-arm, locale
en)
• Flutter version 2.2.2 at /Users/haroonkhan/development/flutter
• Framework revision d79295af24 (6 days ago), 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
• Engine revision 91c9fc8fe0
• Dart version 2.13.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Users/haroonkhan/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 12.5, Build version 12E262
• CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.0)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • BB8DA5E7-D3C6-4F20-BF7C-B72B2092441B • ios
• com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 (simulator)
• Chrome (web)               • chrome                               •
web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.106

• No issues found!